# How to send mp4 response to action on google

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I'm making `action on google` assistant.

How to send **video** response via fulfillment to `action on google`?

Comment: You can currently play audio files only in Actions on Google using [Media Responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses). However, you can add a link to a YouTube video in BasicCard or carousel and clicking it will open YouTube and play the video.